# Radeon card on computer may is defect after current problems. How to check? sddm not start, card detected but no vram

Tags: display, gpu, radeon, sddm

Radeon card on computer may is defect after current problems. How to check? sddm not start, card detected but no vram

My raddeon sapphire has 3 fans. These fans were only turning when had gpu loads to do. Otherwise, in reboot they were still. However, now all three fans working continously.

Display says null display. Sddm is stuch on logind message. My terminal "font" is the basic (large letters) and not the "high-end" font of a graphic card (small letters), as previously.

By the local current problems in Greece (due to fires and heat), i dont know if my graphic card has problem or not. I cant find any util to test its "integrity".

I have gpu utils. It is detected by system as radeon but what else i can do to see if it can work or it is for trash?

- Sddm says is starting but no display in tty7.
- gpu-chk utils says all green and some oranges
- most test utils must open a display to test graphic card
  [image: gpu info][image: inxi info]

UPDATE 1: I changed from sddm to lightdm display manager. However monitor started to low resolution (1080x -75hz). It appears that i cannot change it

UPDATE 2: radeonontop when using glmark2 and glxgear is all values "0".
It appears that GPU is off. VRAM is not detected by radeonontop

it appears that only some very basic display things is working from radeon card :(

See my whole dmesg (nothing of value)
[here](https://pastebin.com/NsZ9DHGe)

my /etc/modules contains only
AMDPowerProfiler

SOLUTION led by Artem S. Tashkinov
running `sudo modprobe amdgpu`
but it was not permanent

i found out that for some reason, amdgpu was blacklisted in my system
at `etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-amdgpu.conf`.

I dont know neither the reason nor the process that led to that.
However, after commenting the line, it was fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and post `sudo dmesg | grep amdgpu output`.

Comment: nothing is displayed... about amdgpu `sudo dmesg | grep amdgpu` - added my whole dmesg, nothing of value

Comment: Your Linux kernel (installation) is broken or you forgot to compile the module. The `amdgpu` module is **required** to drive your GPU. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AMDGPU What does `sudo modprobe amdgpu` return?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov, It was working!!! I used it months. But now.... not... I dont know if some config or other file has been corrupted - how can i find? I am trying to find utils that test GPU / graphic card integrity directly. I cannot remember if amdgpu was installed or not

Comment: What does `sudo modprobe amdgpu` return?

Comment: It solved!!! Resetted my display manager to full resolution and all tests (glxgear and glmark2 on radeontop is not anymore zeroes! Thanks! post that as an answer! Thanks! I was afraid my graphic card is broken!

Comment: how i can make it permanent? it seems at some resets and sudden current poweroffs something changed!